# Como adjuntar un archivo PDF codificado en base 64

Tags: c#, webservice, email, base64

Estoy desarrollando una solución que consulta registros PDF desde un servicio WEB.
El resultado del consumo de este servicio puede ser codificado y almacenado como PDF:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\prueba_" + cf.id_identificador + ".pdf", Convert.FromBase64String(tRespuesta.PDFResultado));
```

Este PDF debe ser enviado mediante correo electrónico, lo cual se podría hacer adjuntan dolo con la misma ruta que se guardo...

Pero el guardar el archivo y luego consultarlo incrementa mucho el tiempo cuando la cantidad de veces que se repite este proceso es muy grande.

Hay alguna manera de adjuntar directamente el resultado del webservice sin guardar el archivo?

```
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
email.To.Add(new MailAddress(destino));
email.From = new MailAddress("example2@example.com");
email.Subject = "Asunto( " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd / MMM / yyy hh:mm:ss") + " ) ";
//email.Attachments.Add();
email.Body = "Do not reply.";
email.IsBodyHtml = false;
email.Priority = MailPriority.High;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya intentaste con `TransferEncoding`

```
Attachment pdfb64= new Attachment(base64String);
pdfb64.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
email.Attachments.Add(pdfb64);
```

Comment: Gracias! si funciono. ayer encontré una forma adicional... como stream: `byte[] stemp= Convert.FromBase64String(tRespuesta.PDFResultado);
                    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(stemp); email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, Path.GetFileName("prueba.pdf"), "application/pdf"));`